# Unable to get custom bullet image to show right of list item

Tags: css, html, formatting, block, spacing

I'm trying to create a LIST with my bullets being check marks just to the right of each list item.

The list needs to be in the CENTER of page.

(I would have posted a graphic example but don't have rep points).

THIS IS WHAT I WANT IN THE CENTER OF THE PAGE.

LIST ITEM 1  ✔
LIST ITEM 2  ✔
LIST ITEM 3  ✔

Right now, my list IS in the center of the page, but the check marks are all the way to the right side of the page.

THIS IS WHAT I HAVE NOW (and do not want).

LIST ITEM 1                                                              ✔
LIST ITEM 2                                                               ✔
LIST ITEM 3                                                               ✔

```
      <div class="welcome-text">

          <div class="welcome-text1">
                <ul class="certs">
                    <li>Licensed</li>
                    <li>bonded</li>
                    <li>insured</li>
                </ul>
          </div>

          <div class="welcome-text2">
                The BEST Choice For Quality Termite Pest &amp; Lawn Care! Protecting your home starts with a free inspection.
          </div>

  </div>
```

Here is the CSS for the above:

```
.welcome-text{
    padding-top:30px;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:80%;
    overflow:hidden;

}

.welcome-text1{
    color:#333333;
    font-family:Open Sans Condensed;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size:24px;
    line-height:30px;
}

.welcome-text1 ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left: 0;
}

.welcome-text ul li{
    display:block;
    background-color:#CCC;
    background: url(images/checkmark.png) right center no-repeat;

}

.welcome-text2{
    color:#777;
    font-family:tahoma;
    font-size:18px;
    line-height:20px;
}


.certs li{
    list-style: none;
    padding:3px;
    margin:0;

}
```

Any ideas?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

If you just need your bullets to appear in the right side, you can simply use

```
<ul dir="rtl" type="disc">
```

Then just change the bullets by images using list-style-type and all... I think it will solve your problem.

Comment: Okay, I added the code you have provided for the UL. But exactly how/where would I put the list-style-type? I tried to put it under my container ul li, but it did not work.

Comment: I added the code you show, and I changed my CSS with the following code, but it does not show the bullets. What am I missing? '.welcome-text1 ul li{
 display:block;
 padding-right:25px;
 background-color:#CCC;
 list-style-type:none;
 background url(images/checkmark.png) no-repeat top left;

}'

Comment: 1st thing u did (in your question),was a trick to show bullet images or checkmark images as bullets.Actually they were just background, not bullets. But the way I told, makes original bullets. So you can't treat them like background images. So,you should not use 'background url(images/checkmark.png)'.Neither you should add the link in li tag. You need to add them in ul tag. Just like, 
'ul
{ 
list-style-type:none;
list-style-image:url('images/checkmark.png');
}'

Just refer to the solution 2 of this article.
[link]http://voidcanvas.com/how-to-place-bullets-of-tag-after-the-text-of-each/[/link]

Comment: Okay, I'm a little (no, a lot) confused. I want to replace any standard bullet with a checkmark image as the bullets. They should act like bullets so that when I shrink the width of the webpage the checkmarks do not increase and decrease spacing between the line text and the bullet checkmark picture.  So which of these suggestions would do that? (sorry I'm a pain)

Comment: y sorry dude?? :O
Anyways, in your case the best method is the 2nd solution in the article link which I provided. Or do 1 thing, u mail me the check images, I will make a demo and will send u.
My email id is go2mailshan@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a width on the ul.

```
.welcome-text1 ul{
  width:50%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aL3Ap/

Comment: Adding width:50% simply made the width of the DIV 50% within the welcome-text Div container, and had the ill effect of aligning to the left side of that container rather than in the center. I added "margin:0 auto" to center it. However, the check marks are still all the way to the right side of its Div container rather than just to the right of the list items itself. I am unable to get this DIV to wrap the list items.

Comment: did you view the jsFiddle I set up? The width should be ul and that should not effect the div wrapping around it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use pseudo-element to show your marks http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/IJtzi

Actually, just a padding on your image if it stans in HTML) , and this is it

Comment: The -------> was included ONLY to show the spacing my page shows, not what I want.  What I want is the first example where the list items are centered on my page with the check marks JUST TO THE RIGHT of the list items, say with little spacing whatsoever. In other words, like bullets on the right side rather than the left. Thx.

Comment: I have removed the ----- so as not to confuse. Sorry.

Comment: no problem, is that what you looked for then http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/IJtzi ?

Answer (score 0):

Just give a width to your ul tag, and it will be done

Comment: This answer is no different than the first answer that I replied to. It did not solve it.